# Discord JS V13 Can't Send Message to Guild Owner

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to send a message to the guild owner when the bot joins a server:

```js
client.on('guildCreate', guild => {
    const introembed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('Hiya!')
        .setColor('RANDOM')
        .setDescription(`Thank you for adding me to your server!\nRun \`${prefix}help\` to get my commands!\nThings to know: I am still under developement, and will have a few bugs, feel free to report them with \`${prefix}bugreport\`\nMy GitHub can be found here: https://github.com/*********/*****`)
        guild.fetchOwner().then(send({ embeds: [introembed]}).catch(console.error()))
})
```

This doesent work, and as of discord.js v13, I can no longer do `guild.owner.send()`. How do I do this in v13?

Comment: "*This doesent work*" isn't a particularly helpful problem statement. Edit your question to include specific details on why the code you've provided doesn't meet your requirements (error messages, expected vs. actual behaviors, etc.). See also: [ask]

Comment: "*I can no longer do `guild.owner.send()`*" Can you clarify this statement? `GuildMember.send()` is still supported, according to [the documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=send).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. You just used the wrong syntax for your [`.then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then). I'd recommend using [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) and [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await).

Try this:

```
client.on("guildCreate", async (guild) => {
  const owner = await guild.fetchOwner();
  owner.send("This is a test message to the owner of this guild!");
});
```

Or if you want to stick to the `.then()` syntax use this:

```
client.on("guildCreate", async (guild) => {
  guild.fetchOwner().then((owner) =>
    owner.send({
      embeds: [
        new MessageEmbed({
          title: "Hiya!",
          color: "RANDOM",
          description: "This is a test message to the owner of this guild!",
        }),
      ],
    })
  );
});
```

Whatever way you choose, when running the code you are going to receive a discord DM like this:
[image: DM to guild owner]